# math.ceil() has a weird behavior...math.ceil(122.0000000000000001) showing 122 while math.ceil(122.00000001) showing 123

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

math.ceil(122.0000000000000001)
showing 122
while 
math.ceil(122.00000001)
showing 123

There is a limit in math.ceil and why is that for.

Comment: Your first number can't be represented as a double precision float, so it is not what you expect. There are tons of questions about this if you care to search

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs **before** `math.ceil` is called:

```
>>> 122.0000000000000001
122.0
>>> 122.00000001
122.00000001
```